# get vars from another file ansible

Tags: variables, ansible

I would like to know the syntax that would allow me to retrieve the contents of a file and use it to make a variable in a new file

in my example I have my YAML configuration file and I have a VARIABLE file and I do not know how to get my first line and make it a variable in my 1st file

````
########## config.yml ############
---
- hosts: my-computer
  remote_user: toto
  tasks:

-vars:
   - my-first-vars: {{ THIS IS VARS }}

- name: "config host"
   lineinfile:
   path: /etc/file.cfg
   regexp: '(.*)this_to_change_with_vars(.*)'
   line: '{{ my-first-vars }}'

```########### file.vars #########

THIS IS VARS : 10.10.10.10
THIS IS OTHER VARS: 10.10.9.9
````

Comment: have you considered using `include_vars` in your actual playbooks?

Comment: coul you make an exemple please

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `vars_files`.

e.g.

```
- hosts: my-computer
  remote_user: toto
  vars_files: 
    - file.vars
  tasks:
    - name: "config host"
      lineinfile:
      path: /etc/file.cfg
      regexp: '(.*)this_to_change_with_vars(.*)'
      line: '{{ my-first-vars }}'
```

and in your file.vars just directly add your var as

```
my-first-vars: 10.10.10.10
```

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good time to use `templates`:

```
- name: config host
  template:
    src: template/file.cfg.j2
    dest: /etc/file.cfg
    mode: 0644
```

the file `file.cfg.j2` should be a copy of the file you want to copy at the `dest` path. Your variables goes in the `j2` file and can be change at each interaction.

example:

```
vi file.cfg.j2

my cfg file
{{ my-first-vars }}
```